# How i can refresh wpf form or list view on click event performed on second form while performing updates on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, listview, wpf-controls

I have list view on first forms if i select a row and click edit button second form open their i do updates in selected row and click ok then database get updated but i don't know how to update list view display on first form according to updated database?

Comment: hope the question is clear ...Note: I am using Wpf in C#

Comment: i am not using any framework

Comment: instead of placing those in the comments use the `edit` button at the bottom of your post, to keep it easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I will bite the bullet and give you an answer... note that this will be all I offer, no long discussion!

Your ListView will be bound to an IEnumerable of data objects. You will be passing the selected data object to the second form, so any operation done on that data object in the second form will instantly show up in the first form - because you passed an object it is by reference, both forms are looking at the same thing.

As for updating after the database save - you can save yourself some trouble and only get a fresh copy of the data object if there was a problem with the save (so what is currently in the database doesn't match the contents of the data object), or if there is more than one concurrent user of the database. If this is the case then you know the identifier of the data, just fetch a new copy then replace the data row in the IEnumerable that the ListView is bound to.

Remember: data binding is your friend. And it is easy to insert and remove from a list.